# MYSQL - WHERE CLAUSE - Concatenating columns in IN clause

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
SELECT * FROM my_tbl1
WHERE id IN ( SELECT id1 FROM my_tbl2 WHERE user_id=2)
OR    id IN ( SELECT id2 FROM my_tbl2 WHERE user_id=2)
OR    id IN ( SELECT id3 FROM my_tbl2 WHERE user_id=2)
OR    id IN ( SELECT id4 FROM my_tbl2 WHERE user_id=2)
OR    id IN ( SELECT id5 FROM my_tbl2 WHERE user_id=2)

.......
OR    id IN ( SELECT id22 FROM my_tbl2 WHERE user_id=2)
```

**id1** and **id2** and ... so on **id22** are columns in **my_tbl2** . This is making me to write **OR** clause 22 times and hitting the my_tbl2 again and again .

I tried **GROUP_CONCAT** but that one returns just string of values separated by commas .So this doesn't work

I mean the below query doesn't help

```
 SELECT * FROM my_tbl1
    WHERE id IN ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id1,id2,id3..id22) FROM my_tbl2 WHERE user_id=2)
```

The other thought , I am worried subquery with **IN CLAUSE**

```
   SELECT * FROM my_tbl1 a 
        WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM my_tbl2 b 
    WHERE b.user_id=2 AND a.id IN (b.id1,b.id2,b.id3...b.id22 )
```

Is there any way I can simplify this one ?

Thank You

Comment: It looks like your schema should be improved, if you have 22 columns to test against.

Comment: Thanks wilx , Unfortunately that was a old table ( I gave you +1 for your comment too :) ) . Creating indexes making mess out of it . We redesigned and brought it down to 8 columns . But still querying 8 columns and righting 8 subqueries made me sick and so thought they will be some other good approch

Comment: Your table design seems a bit strange to me in general. What is that my_tbl2, has it 22 columns that are named id1, id2...? Could you provide some sample rows with pseudo values?

Comment: Thanks  user1902288 . True unfortunately we got this table design from famous car manufacturer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about using `FIND_IN_SET()`?

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID, (SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',id1,id2,id3,...,id22)  
                       FROM my_tbl2 
                       WHERE user_id=2)) > 0
```

or using `JOIN` and `IN`

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    my_tbl1 a
        INNER JOIN my_tbl2 b
            ON a.id IN (b.id1,b.id2,b.id3,...,b.id22)
WHERE   b.user_id = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for this function . But using function in WHERE CLAUSE

Answer (score 1):

```
select my_tbl1.* from my_tbl1,my_tbl2
where (id=id1 or id=i2 ... or id=id22) and user_id=2
```

Comment: I'd want to run an `EXPLAIN SELECT` over that before using it in production; that conditionless inner-join makes me nervous, and I'd want to be very sure that the query-planner was doing the right thing with it.